# Get posts from multi category (no wordpress, pure php and mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post, categories

There are 2 MySQL tables: 'posts' and 'category'. Unfortunately there is no taxonomy table.

Categories:

```
id: integer
name: string
```

Posts:

```
id: integer
name: string
body: text
tag: string
category: string
```

So, in category there is:

```
 id    name
 1     Books
 2     Animals
```

And Post:

```
 id    name     body      tag      category
 1     My Post  Hi post   my-post  1
 2     Post 2   2nd Post  post-2   1;2
```

This is te SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '1'`

Only returns post id 1

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '2'`

Returns nothing

How can I get both posts with just one SQL query?

Comment: This is a really bad way to store categories. You can use the `LIKE` keyword to try and accomplish what you want, but you will quickly find there are a lot of flaws with that approach. For example, if I said `WHERE category LIKE '%1%', I will get any category with a 1: 1, 11, 12, 13..., 21.. and so on. It is very hard to distinguish a single 1 by the way you've designed htis.

Comment: I know, It was like that when I saw it for the first time. I have tried `LIKE`, but it returns category 1, category 11, category 111 and so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would steer well clear of that structure and create a new table `PostCategory`to house your associated categories for each post so:

```
postID | categoryID
1      | 1
2      | 1
2      | 2
```

Then use a distinct select and an inner join in your sql:

```
select distinct post.* from post 
inner join postcategory on post.id = postcategory.postID 
where postcategory.categoryID = 2;
```

As @McAdam331 quite rightly said, using a string to store lookup values you're going to be querying is B.A.D for performance and in general for db design

Comment: This is perfect. I'm really glad someone took the time to demonstrate what the new table would look like. For reference of others, see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Thanks guys, it seems a much better solution